# Why does this piece of code work in the opposite way?

Tags: c++, camera, mouse

I have this piece of code that is supposed to test mouse movement and change the camera if it does:

```
POINT myMouse;
GetCursorPos(&myMouse);

float Sensitivity = 10;

if(myMouse.x != middleX || myMouse.y != middleY)
{
    float DifferenceX = myMouse.x - middleX;
    float DifferenceY = myMouse.y - middleY;

    Rotation -> y += DifferenceX/Sensitivity;
    Rotation -> x -= DifferenceY/Sensitivity;
    if(Rotation -> x > 90) Rotation -> x = 90;
    if(Rotation -> x < -90) Rotation -> x = -90;
    if(Rotation -> y > 360) Rotation -> y = 0;

    SetCursorPos(middleX, middleY);
}
```

For some reason, DifferenceX is actually the Y axis and DifferenceY is actually X axis.

Why is this?

Comment: To clarify, are you saying the code in the question gives the correct results, using incorrect logic?
Can you confirm that you don't have your own redefinition of POINT with y&x defined in the opposite order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Rotation -> y += DifferenceX/Sensitivity;
           //^^ y and x seems reversed
 Rotation -> x -= DifferenceY/Sensitivity;
```

probably should be

```
 Rotation -> x += DifferenceX/Sensitivity;
 Rotation -> y -= DifferenceY/Sensitivity;
```

Comment: You'd think that but moving the mouse left and right tilts the camera up and down

Comment: @Split so this actually is not the cause of the strange error?

Comment: I was just wondering why it only works if its the wrong way around